# Directive initialized before its children

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 directives one responsible for the master element `<swapview>` and the other for its children `<view>`.
However by the time the children templates are loaded `var views = $('view', elem);` is already executed and finds 0 `<view>` elements in the DOM.

I just lack an experience about that issue any ideas would be very helpful

1. How can I workaround that async issue?
2. I'm not sure that this pattern of dependable directives is the proper way. I would appreciate any tip on that or a resource of a good practice  I can examine.

HTML:

```
<swapview>
  <view ng-repeat="view in views" templateurl="{{::view.template}}"></view>
</swapview>
```

js

```
  App.directive('view', function () {
    return {
      scope:{
        templateurl: '@'
      },
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.getTemplateUrl = function () {
          return $scope.templateurl;
        };
      },
      template: '<ng-include src="getTemplateUrl()"/>' 
    };
  });


  App.directive('swapview', ['$swipe',function ($swipe) {
    //....        

    return {
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

        var views = $('view', elem);
        var count = views.length;

        //......    
      },
      require: 'view'
    };
  }]);


  var ctrls = ang.module('controllers',[]);

  ctrls.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.views = [
      {template:'templates/viewI.html'},
      {template:'templates/viewII.html'},
      {template:'templates/viewIII.html'},
      {template:'templates/viewIV.html'}
    ];
  }]);
```

Appreciate your kind help

Comment: You cannot rely on the HTML (using jQuery) on intiialization, unless you hack a `$timeout` to wait for angular digest cycle. But do you really need jQuery there? Wouldn't `scope.views.length` give you the same `count`?

Comment: @floribon I actually need the `<view>` elements in order to interact with them. This is just a part of my code for a simple illustration of the problem.

Comment: what exactly does the `swapview` directive need to get from each of the `views`? Usually, you would be passing data from parent to the children with attributes (like the `templateurl` attribute) rather than some other roundabout way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relying on the child DOM elements being there during `link`-phase is a very fragile approach.

It would work when the elements are already there:

```
<swapview>
  <view templateUrl="view1.html"></view>
  <view templateUrl="view2.html"></view>
</swapview>
```

but **would not work** if you had an `ng-if` or `ng-repeat`, because these two directives transclude themselves and only evaluate whether to render themselves "slightly later", so in `link` you would see a placeholder comment (even if `ng-if="true") instead:

```
<swapview>
  <view ng-if="true" templateUrl="view1.html">
</swapview>
```

You *could* overcome this with a (hackish) `$timeout` approach - it would not cause a race condition - that's not what is hackish - and would actually work every time (even with 0 delay), because `$timeout` places the execution at the end of the digest cycle:

```
console.log(element.find("view").length); // will output 0
$timeout(function(){
  console.log(element.find("view").length); // will output 1
});
```

Still, this is not a good solution. This would break if the user of your directive decides to load the contents dynamically, for example with `ng-include`. So, the following **will not work** even with `$timeout` if the the template needs to be downloaded:

```
<swapview>
   <div ng-include="'templateForViews.html`"></div>
<swapview>
```

**So, what works?**

The proper way to deal with expected child directives is to have the child directives register themselves with the parent a controller with `require: "^parent"`:

```
.directive("swapview", function($timeout){
  return {
    controller: function(){
      var childViewCtrls = [];

      this.registerView = function(view, viewEl){
        childViewCtrls.push({ctrl: view, elem: viewEl});
      };
    },
    link: function(scope, element){
      //
    }
  };
})

.directive("view", function($timeout){
  return {
    require: ["view", "^swapview"],
    controller: function(){
      // useful to expose an API
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls){
      var me = ctrls[0],
          swapview = ctrls[1];

      swapview.registerView(me, element);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation it was very helpful and a great learning experience. Although I needed the elements in the `swapview.link` I grasp the idea and modify it to work in my case with some async code.
Thank you.